# Stuck with adding edit/delete action buttons to angular datatable

Tags: angular7

I'm using angular 7 in my application. I've installed 'angular-datatables' in my application. I'm able to populate data. But i'm stuck with adding action buttons. Not sure how to do this. Also not getting much help from google.

Component.ts

```
export class ParentListComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtUsers = [
    { "fatherName": 101, "motherName": "Anil", "guardian": "Singh", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 102, "motherName": "Reena", "guardian": "Singh", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 103, "motherName": "Aradhay", "guardian": "Simgh", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 104, "motherName": "Dilip", "guardian": "Singh", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 105, "motherName": "Alok", "guardian": "Singh", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 106, "motherName": "Sunil", "guardian": "Singh", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 107, "motherName": "Sushil", "guardian": "Singh", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 108, "motherName": "Sheo", "guardian": "Shan", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 109, "motherName": "Niranjan", "guardian": "R", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 110, "motherName": "Lopa", "guardian": "Mudra", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" },
    { "fatherName": 111, "motherName": "Paramanand", "guardian": "Tripathi", "mobile": "121231313", "email": "abc@gmail.com" }
  ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      //dom: 'lrtip', // to hide search bar
      data: this.dtUsers,
      columns: [
        { title: 'Father Name', data: 'fatherName' },
        { title: 'Mother Name', data: 'motherName' },
        { title: 'Guardian', data: 'guardian' },
        { title: 'Mobile', data: 'mobile' },
        { title: 'Email', data: 'email' }
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

component.html

```
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
          <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"></table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need a package to show a table that simple? I think you can use basic html and angular loop

Comment: @SebastienB.. Thanks for replyiing. But I didn't get what you are talking about. Can you help me in adding action buttons llike Edit/Delete to angular- datatable

Comment: my question is why are you using 'angular-datatable', it seems useless for simple data like that

Comment: data looks simple now.. may be later there might be some lakhs of records and i need to use angular-datatable..